# SQL - How to remove HTML tags on Select

Tags: html, sql, tags

I have a row in a MySQL table with some HTML tags.

I need export this table to an Excel xls, without this tags.

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(HTML_ROW,'<br>',''),'</font>',''),'</b>',''),'<font size="2pt" color="#676767">',' | '),'<font  color="#00c9ff"><b>',''),'<font  color="#009f9f"><b>',''),'<font  color="#e25ac6"><b>',''),'<font  color="#008cff"><b>',''),'<font  color="#c60c9e"><b>','') FROM MYTABLE
```

With REPLACE function its works.. but If I change any record on the table, I need to remake the SELECT..

And - of course - I think, this isn't the fast and best way to do this.

There is another way to replace all HTML tags on SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql did not support wild char or regexp in replace function AFAIK. 
I would suggest you keep the result as is, then remove tags in excel, if you cannot enum all possible tags in your query.

Comment: Hi zee! tks for reply! I never put the tags on the row, but - as usual - my client asked for a change that forced me to it.. And the EXCEL XLS will be a "AUTO-REPORT" for this client - he will export directly on website. Then.. I cannot send to him the report with this tags. Well.. tks for the reply! Help me a lot!! :D